# Favorites disappears from sidebar in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Running Mountain Lion 10.8.3 I find that after a recent reboot my Favorites have all disappeared from the sidebar in Finder.

Finder > Preferences > Sidebar shows a number of boxes against Favorite folders, but these can not be selected

Comment: Try deleting the preferences with `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Finder.plist; killall Finder`. Does Console.app show any relevant log messages?

Comment: Do you have the same question, but 9 years later?  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/450169/17600, which asks about macOS 12.

Answer (score 5):

This could be due to having collapsed "Favorites" inadvertently.

Try simply hovering over the heading "Favorites" in the sidebar; the collapsed arrow will appear: ">"; click on it to expand "Favorites"

This toggles the favorites on and off...

Comment: I had the same problem, I can't believe I didn't realise they're hidden *facepalm*. Thanks XD

Comment: Oh wow, talk about being the simple stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Hold together <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> and then relaunch "Finder" that will solve your problem instantly.  If the problem persists, please try reinstall Mac OS X by <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> after rebooting.

Comment: You might not want to claim it "will" solve the problem instantly if in the next sentence you plan to say, "if it persists." In fact, your first directive may solve the problem sometimes, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

I've just wanted to share what has just worked on my system (10.12.6):

```
sudo killall sharedfilelistd Finder
```

and my Favourites are back.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried killing sharedfilelistd on it's own, messing with plist files, among other things - this seemed to be the final thing I needed to restore my favourites on 10.14

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem on Yosemite. Hovering over "Favorites" and clicking "Show" worked.